# Protobuf-Net Empty List

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Came across protobuf-net, awesome! I have a question regarding serialization of empty lists.

I start by declaring the object I want to serialize:

```
[ProtoContract]
class TestClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    List<int> _listOfInts = new List<int>();

    public TestClass() { }

    public List<int> ListOfInts
    {
        get { return _listOfInts; }
        set { _listOfInts = value; }
    }
}
```

If _listOfInts is empty (but not null) when I deserialse this object is will always be null. This makes sense looking at the protobuf convention and I currently work around this by adding the following method:

```
[ProtoAfterDeserialization]
private void OnDeserialize()
{
    if (_listOfInts == null)
        _listOfInts = new List<int>();
}
```

My question is whether I can achieve this same functionality in a more concise fashion, possibly with an additional attirbute which will initialise null/empty objects as empty instead of null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to protect against a null list you could try lazy loading in the property getter.

```
public List<int> ListOfInts
{
    get { return _listOfInts ?? (_listOfInts = new List<int>()); }
    set { _listOfInts = value; }
}
```

This way you can just allow the serializer to return null.

Comment: This is a possibility I had not considered, would up vote you if I could. I'm still primarily interested to know if there is an attribute that would do this for me though.

Comment: Have you tried the [DefaultValue] attribute? Not sure if you could initialize lists but worth a try.

Comment: @Jras I did consider adding such, but every time I've looked at it, it turns out to actually make people's code worse, not better

Comment: @Marc Gravell I agree, If the list should never be null it should be handled in the Property and not in the serializer.

Answer (score 7):

There's a fundamental issue here in terms of how protobuf encodes data: the list itself *does not appear* in the data - just the elements. Because of this, there is simply nowhere obvious to store information about the list. It can be spoofed by sending a Boolean using conditional serialization, but frankly that is a bit hacky and ugly - and adds complexity. Personally, I strongly advise abstracting away from lists that could ever be null. For example:

```
private readonly List<Foo> items = new List<Foo>();
[ProtoMember(1)]
public List<Foo> Items { get { return items; } }
```

Or

```
private List<Foo> items;
[ProtoMember(1)]
public List<Foo> Items { get { return items ?? (items = new List<Foo>()); } }
```

And note that this advice isn't just about serialization: it is about avoiding arbitrary null-reference-exceptions. People don't usually expect sub-collections to be null.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't initialise the collection on the private items field?  I can see that if you haven't accessed the getter of the Items property you're not hanging on to an empty collection reference, but you're paying the price of a null check every time.  Is it just situational?